# Python create file in certain directory with open()

Tags: python

My code:

```
boyka = "hello"
f = open("~/Desktop/" + boyka + ".txt", "a")
f.write(boyka)
f.close
```

result:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/hello.txt'
```

Shouldn't the script create the file since it's "a" ? How can I fix the code?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: If the problem can't be reproduced, like NightShadeQueen says, the problem must be with the path "~/Desktop/".

Comment: @NightShadeQueen and m69, Problem solved. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` function would not automatically expand the `~` to the users home directory. It is instead trying to create in a directory with exactly that name. I am guessing that is not what you want. In which case you should use - [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) , to expand `~` to the user's home directory. Example -

```
import os.path
f = open(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~/Desktop",boyka + ".txt")), "a")
```

I would also like to suggest you to use `os.path.join()` to create the paths , rather than manually creating them.

Comment: Thanks. Worked exactly like i wanted it to